# CSS on hover display hidden div not working

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
 <div class="top-container">
    <div class="primary-text">lorem</div>
    <div class="secondary-text">lorem</div>
</div>
<div class="secondary-container">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
</div>
<div class="info-container">
   <div class="container-one">
       <div class="box1">1</div>
       <h3>lorem</h3>
       <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.</p>
    </div>
   <div class="container-two">
    <div class="box2">2</div>
    <h3>lorem</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="container-three">
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <h3>lorem</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="info-sec">
    <img src="test.png" alt="blah">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Relavent CSS:

```
.info-sec{
visibility:hidden;

}
.box:hover + .info-sec{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

If I change the hover from the box to the info-container it works fine:

```
.info-container:hover + .info-sec{
visibility:visible;
}
```

But hovering using box does not work. I've also tried using display: none; and display: block;

Codepen: https://codepen.io/colton-22/pen/jOwoMxL

Comment: Because [`+` is an adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator). `.info-sec` is not an adjacent sibling of `.box`. In fact, they are on different nesting levels, and CSS cannot "traverse" up nesting levels. This also explains why `.info-container:hover + .info-sec` works.

Comment: first of all, never include tags such as `<html>` or `<title>` tags in **CodePen**, it just expects the tags that are **with-in** the `<body>` tag. No, you can not even include the `<body>`

Answer (score 1):

The **+ is adjacent Sibling Selector**. So when you use:

```
.info-container:hover + .info-sec{
visibility:visible;
}
```

It works because **info-sec is the first next sibling of info-container**. But when you use:

```
.box:hover + .info-sec{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

It doesn't work because **info-sec is not the sibling of info-container**.

According to my knowledge, there is no selector in css which works for you. So, you have to use javascript to achieve this.